# Cut an array and put it before the first index of array JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

`var myArray = ["Apple","Banana","Orange","Coconut"];`

I want the array become this: `["Orange","Coconut","Apple","Banana"];`

Which is to put the index 3 , 4 of the array to the 0,1 position and the 0,1 of the array be placed in 3,4 of the array.
This is my method, but I hope to see better way:

```
var myArray = [1,2,3,4];
var myArray2 = myArray.splice(0,2);
myArray.concat(myArray2);
```

Comment: You can also use `.splice()` to insert the removed elements.  That will modify the original array rather than return a new array like `.concat()` and will allow you to insert it wherever you want.

Comment: If you used `.splice()` to insert multiple elements you'd get a sub-array within your array.

Comment: @Aweary depends how you use it

Answer (score 1):

That's three lines which can be further reduced to two if you:

```
var myArray = myArray.concat(myArray.splice(0,2));
```

I don't think it's going to get much better than that.